# C GTK+4.0 window not showing all elements

Tags: c, gtk

For some reason, we cannot get the 2 images in the `user_image_box` and `filtered_image_box` to be horizontally next to each other, above the button boxes.

Either we can get them to be vertical with each other, or as it is with the code below invisible in the window which is not ideal.

We're not totally sure what the problem is, so any suggestions or pointers to try would be helpful. The GitHub for the repo is available at: https://github.com/VerzatileDevOrg/C_image_processing

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#include "filters/black_and_white_filter.c"
#include "filters/bright_filter.c"
#include "filters/dark_filter.c"
#include "filters/emboss_filter.c"
#include "filters/negative_filter.c"
#include "filters/pixelate_filter.c"
#include "filters/rgb_to_gray_filter.c"
#include "filters/sepia_filter.c"

// callback functions for all filters
static void black_and_white_filter_apply(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    GtkWidget *image = data;

    black_and_white_filter("assets/images/test_image.bmp", "assets/images/test_image_bright.bmp");
    gtk_image_set_from_file(GTK_IMAGE(image), "assets/images/test_image_black_and_white.bmp");
    g_print("Black And White Filter Has Been Applied\n");
}

static void bright_filter_apply(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    GtkWidget *image = data;

    bright_filter("assets/images/test_image.bmp", "assets/images/test_image_bright.bmp");
    gtk_image_set_from_file(GTK_IMAGE(image), "assets/images/test_image_bright.bmp");
    g_print("Bright Filter Has Been Applied\n");
}

static void dark_filter_apply(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    GtkWidget *image = data;

    dark_filter("assets/images/test_image.bmp", "assets/images/test_image_dark.bmp");
    gtk_image_set_from_file(GTK_IMAGE(image), "assets/images/test_image_dark.bmp");
    g_print("Dark Filter Has Been Applied\n");
}

static void emboss_filter_apply(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    GtkWidget *image = data;

    emboss_filter("assets/images/test_image.bmp", "assets/images/test_image_emboss.bmp");
    gtk_image_set_from_file(GTK_IMAGE(image), "assets/images/test_image_emboss.bmp");
    g_print("Emboss Filter Has Been Applied\n");
}

static void negative_filter_apply(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    GtkWidget *image = data;

    negative_filter("assets/images/test_image.bmp", "assets/images/test_image_negative.bmp");
    gtk_image_set_from_file(GTK_IMAGE(image), "assets/images/test_image_negative.bmp");
    g_print("Negative Filter Has Been Applied\n");
}

static void pixelate_filter_apply(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    GtkWidget *image = data;

    pixelate_filter("assets/images/test_image.bmp", "assets/images/test_image_pixelate.bmp");
    gtk_image_set_from_file(GTK_IMAGE(image), "assets/images/test_image_pixelate.bmp");
    g_print("Pixelate Filter Has Been Applied\n");
}

static void rgb_to_gray_filter_apply(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    GtkWidget *image = data;

    rgb_to_gray_filter("assets/images/test_image.bmp", "assets/images/test_image_rgb_to_gray.bmp");
    gtk_image_set_from_file(GTK_IMAGE(image), "assets/images/test_image_rgb_to_gray.bmp");
    g_print("RGB To Gray Filter Has Been Applied\n");
}

static void sepia_filter_apply(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    GtkWidget *image = data;

    sepia_filter("assets/images/test_image.bmp", "assets/images/test_image_sepia.bmp");
    gtk_image_set_from_file(GTK_IMAGE(image), "assets/images/test_image_sepia.bmp");
    g_print("Sepia Filter Has Been Applied\n");
}

// struct for filter buttons
typedef struct
{
    const char *label;
    void (*callback)(GtkWidget *, gpointer);
} FilterButtonInfo;

// connect filter buttons to callback functions
void connect_filter_buttons(GtkWidget *image, const FilterButtonInfo *button_info, int num_buttons, GtkWidget *button_box)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num_buttons; ++i)
    {
        GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new_with_label(button_info[i].label);
        g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(button_info[i].callback), image);
        gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(button_box), button);
    }
}

static void activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget *window, *box, *image_container, *image, *filtered_image, *user_image_box,
        *filtered_image_box, *button_box0, *button_box1, *button0,
        *button1, *button2, *button3, *button4, *button5, *button6,
        *button7;
    const char *css = "window {"
                      "    background-color: #FFFFE4;"
                      "}"
                      "headerbar.titlebar {"
                      "    font-family: BigNoodleTitling;"
                      "    font-size: 36px;"
                      "    color: black;"
                      "    background-color: #4CAF50;"
                      "    border: none;"
                      "    padding: 10px 20px;"
                      "    text-decoration: none;"
                      "}"
                      "button {"
                      "    background-color: #4CAF50;"
                      "    color: black;"
                      "    2px solid #008CBA;"
                      "    padding: 10px 20px;"
                      "    text-decoration: none;"
                      "    font-size: 22px;"
                      "    margin: 8px 5px;"
                      "    font-family: BigNoodleTitling;"
                      "}";
    FilterButtonInfo filter_buttons[] = {
        {"Black And White Filter", black_and_white_filter_apply},
        {"Bright Filter", bright_filter_apply},
        {"Dark Filter", dark_filter_apply},
        {"Emboss Filter", emboss_filter_apply},
        {"Negative Filter", negative_filter_apply},
        {"Pixelate Filter", pixelate_filter_apply},
        {"RGB To Gray Filter", rgb_to_gray_filter_apply},
        {"Sepia Filter", sepia_filter_apply}};
    int num_filter_buttons = sizeof(filter_buttons) / sizeof(filter_buttons[0]);

    // create new window
    window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "C Image Processing");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 800, 800);
    gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);

    // create new vertical box container
    box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
    gtk_widget_set_halign(box, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
    gtk_widget_set_valign(box, GTK_ALIGN_END);
    // include box container in window
    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window), box);

    image_container = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);
    gtk_widget_set_halign(image_container, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
    gtk_widget_set_valign(image_container, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
    gtk_box_set_homogeneous(GTK_BOX(image_container), TRUE);
    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(box), image_container);

    // create new horizontal box container for user image
    user_image_box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);
    gtk_widget_set_halign(user_image_box, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
    gtk_widget_set_valign(user_image_box, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
    gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom(user_image_box, 20);
    // append user image box to vertical box
    gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(image_container), user_image_box);
    // create image widget
    image = gtk_image_new_from_file("assets/images/test_image.bmp");
    gtk_image_set_pixel_size(GTK_IMAGE(image), 250);
    // append user image widget to user image box
    gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(user_image_box), image);

    // create new horizontal box container for filtered image
    filtered_image_box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);
    gtk_widget_set_halign(filtered_image_box, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
    gtk_widget_set_valign(filtered_image_box, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
    gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom(filtered_image_box, 20);
    // append filtered image box to vertical box
    gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(image_container), filtered_image_box);
    // create image widget
    filtered_image = gtk_image_new_from_file("assets/images/test_image.bmp");
    gtk_image_set_pixel_size(GTK_IMAGE(filtered_image), 250);
    // append user image widget to filtered image box
    gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(filtered_image_box), filtered_image);

    // create new horizontal box container for buttons
    button_box0 = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);
    gtk_widget_set_halign(button_box0, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
    gtk_widget_set_valign(button_box0, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
    // append button box to vertical box
    gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(box), button_box0);

    // create new horizontal box container for buttons
    button_box1 = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);
    gtk_widget_set_halign(button_box1, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
    gtk_widget_set_valign(button_box1, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
    gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom(button_box1, 20);
    // append button box to vertical box
    gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(box), button_box1);

    // connect filter buttons to callback functions
    connect_filter_buttons(image, filter_buttons, num_filter_buttons / 2, button_box0);
    connect_filter_buttons(image, filter_buttons + num_filter_buttons / 2, num_filter_buttons / 2, button_box1);

    // create new CSS provider object and load CSS
    GtkCssProvider *provider = gtk_css_provider_new();
    gtk_css_provider_load_from_string(provider, css);
    // add CSS provider to default display
    gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_display(
        gdk_display_get_default(),
        GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(provider),
        GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);

    // show window
    gtk_widget_set_visible(window, TRUE);
}
```